# unrecognized configuration section system.servicemodel/domainServices

Tags: asp.net, domainservices, service-model

In visual studio 2010 and 2012, i cant add an item domain service...
I have this message after naming my service :

"unrecognized configuration section system service-model domain-services"

after click on OK, nothing has been create...

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the existing domain and service model in the web.config file.
And it works fine.